# How to map values from one dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes as follows:

```py
df.head()
    
ext_id  credit_debit_indicator  index_name  business_date   trench_tag  trench_tag_l2
0   4SL19N2YQLCU62TY    C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
1   1EXHR74Y2YXBN4AM    D   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
2   OI0001WMRUD C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
3   OI0001WKKXA C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
4   SGW7000490024199    C   ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999  XXX99
```

and

```py
mapping_df.head()

trench_code trench_level    fink_code   fink_level
0   COM0101001  4   PREPAID_01  2
1   COM0101002  4   PREPAID_01  2
2   COM0101003  4   PREPAID_01  2
3   COM0101099  4   PREPAID_01  2
4   COM0101999  4   PREPAID_01  2
```

I need to match `df.trench_tag` with `mapping_df.trench_code`, and where there's a match, I want to copy `mapping_df.trench_code` into a new column in the original dataset `df.fink_sub_tag_key`. If I don't find a match, then I need to try match `df.trench_code_l2` with `mapping_df.trench_code`.

I tried:

```py
df2 = df.merge(mapping_df, left_on='trench_tag', right_on='trench_code', how='left')
df2 = df.merge(mapping_df, left_on='trench_tag_l2', right_on='trench_code', how='left')
```

where the second join overwrites the first one.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dataframes you provided, modified to include matching examples:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ext_id": [
            "4SL19N2YQLCU62TY",
            "1EXHR74Y2YXBN4AM",
            "OI0001WMRUD",
            "OI0001WKKXA",
            "SGW7000490024199",
        ],
        "credit_debit_indicator": ["C", "D", "C", "C", "C"],
        "index_name": [
            "ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208",
            "ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208",
            "ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208",
            "ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208",
            "ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208",
        ],
        "business_date": [
            "2022-07-31",
            "2022-07-31",
            "2022-07-31",
            "2022-07-31",
            "2022-07-31",
        ],
        "trench_tag": [
            "COM0101001",
            "XXX9999999",
            "XXX9999999",
            "XXX9999999",
            "XXX9999999",
        ],
        "trench_tag_l2": ["XXX99", "XXX99", "XXX99", "COM0101099", "XXX99"],
    }
)

mapping_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "trench_code": [
            "COM0101001",
            "COM0101002",
            "COM0101003",
            "COM0101099",
            "COM0101999",
        ],
        "trench_level": [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        "fink_code": [
            "PREPAID_01",
            "PREPAID_01",
            "PREPAID_01",
            "PREPAID_01",
            "PREPAID_01",
        ],
        "fink_level": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
for (
    col,
    target,
) in {"match1": "trench_tag", "match2": "trench_tag_l2"}.items():
    df[col] = mapping_df.apply(
        lambda x: x["trench_code"] if x["trench_code"] in df[target].values else pd.NA,
        axis=1,
    )
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                             index_name business_date  trench_tag  \
0  ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  COM0101001   
1  ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999   
2  ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999   
3  ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999   
4  ib-prodfulltext-t24-transhist-202208    2022-07-31  XXX9999999   

  trench_tag_l2      match1      match2  
0         XXX99  COM0101001        <NA>  
1         XXX99        <NA>        <NA>  
2         XXX99        <NA>        <NA>  
3    COM0101099        <NA>  COM0101099  
4         XXX99        <NA>        <NA>
```